# How do I create nested routing in vue? Url is pointed but the page isnt loading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

```
{
    path: '/About',
    name: 'About',
    component: About,
      children: [{
      path: '/AddNewDetail',
      name: 'AddNewDetail',
      component: AddNewDetail,
       }]
  },


<router-link to="/About/AddNewDetail"></router-link>
```

the page addnewdetail isnt loading. how to bring in nested url with the component .
Error says: Match not found with the location path

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the slash in front of AddNewDetail.
If you write a slash in front of it, it becomes a root path in your url, so I guess you could reach it under foo.bar/AddNewDetail. If you want to reach under foo.bar/About/AddNewDetail then write without /